# Could lower semicontinuous functions have Lipschitz constant?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, lipschitz-functions

For example, $f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1, & x\ne 0\\ 
0, & 0
\end{matrix}\right.$ is lower semicontinuous. Does it have Lipschitz constant? Beased on defniation $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\leq K|x_1-x_2|$, it seems that there exist $K$ that makes $f(x)$ Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: A function has to be continuous, in fact even more --- uniformly continuous (and this still isn't sufficient), in order to be Lipschitz continuous. Your function is not continuous, so your function is not Lipschitz continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. Consider $|f(0)-f(x_0)| = 1$ for some $x_0\neq 0$. Then we have on the right side of the inequality $K|x_0|$. Choose your $K$, then I choose $0 < x_0 < (1/K)$. Then we have $K|x_0| < K|(1/K)| = 1 = |f(0)-f(x_0)|$.